# Tried importing data from web-world bank and got an error

Tags: pandas, importdata

Code----
from pandas.io.wb import download

YEAR = 2013

GDP_INDICATOR = 'NY.GDP.MKTP.CD'

data = download(indicator=GDP_INDICATOR, country='all',

```
          start=YEAR, end=YEAR)
```

data.head()

### Error message---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11260/1827974983.py in 
----> 1 from pandas.io.wb import download
2
3 YEAR = 2013
4
5 GDP_INDICATOR = 'NY.GDP.MKTP.CD'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io.wb'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Same issuse i have found in one of my project and this piece of code work for me. Try it once.

```
pip install pandas-datareader

from pandas_datareader import wb

world_bank_indicators = ['NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG', 'FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG', 
'GC.TAX.TOTL.GD.ZS', 'NE.EXP.GNFS.ZS', 'NE.IMP.GNFS.ZS']

pip install itables

from itables import init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(all_interactive=True)

df = wb.download(indicator=world_bank_indicators, country=['all'], 
start=2008, end=2019)
df
```